# Leetcode distorts my variable value. Why?

Tags: variables, definition

I encountered really strange behavior of leetcode platform. I defined a static variable timeStamp (you may check it out in the below screenshot) and set it as 0. When I try to print it, the leetcode sdout tells me that the value of the variable is 2. What is the problem here? Thanks!

[A screenshot of the leetcode sdout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z30Wk.png)

Comment: Just a quick question: is there a specific reason why you are using static?

Comment: nope. It turned out that the problem is fixed after the "static" is removed. However, I still don't get the mechanism that produces this error.

Answer (score 0):

Giving a field the `static` storage duration means all instances of `class Solution` share the same variable(s). This means subsequent runs of the harness will contaminate state between different test cases. Removing `static` likely isolated each copy to individual instances, hence why it fixed your issue.